# "Maybe" in German (vielleicht)

Tags: etymology, german

The word **maybe** is pretty much a direct translation of "may be" in all languages I know, with or without concatenation. Examples: **kanske** *(Swedish)*, **måske** *(Danish)*, **peut-être** *(French)*, **может быть** *(Russian)*

However, in German the word is **vielleicht**. What is the etymology behind this?

(I believe there is a construction "kann sein", which fits the above pattern, but I think it's much less common and might have a slightly different use than vielleicht).

Comment: Also in Italian the etymology varies and is not a union of "may/can + be".

Comment: Ok! For some reason (I have no idea why) I thought potessere was the Italian word for maybe.

Comment: Ahah sorry for giggling, that was funny but no, there is no such word. :D The Italian word is **Forse**, coming from Latin **fŏrsit**, union of *fŏrs* ‘destiny/fate’ e *sĭt* ‘be’, as in "so be it", it's conjugated. :).

Comment: Haha, no problems, thanks for the info! (Though admit it's a great word!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The etymology appears to be 'without difficulty, easily'. The second part of the word, *leicht*, continues to be used on its own in the sense of 'easy/easily' - as in *mit Leichtigkeit*, English *with ease, easily*.

The [dictionary by Jacob and Wilhelm Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GV08379) provides the following [etymology](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/genFOplus.tcl?sigle=DWB&lemid=GV08379):

> concatenation of *vil* and Middle High German *lîhte*. In Middle High German and early Modern High German, the latter still has [by itself] the meaning of Modern High German *vielleicht* [...]; Middle High German *vil lîhte* was not only used in the sense of 'easily, without difficulty', but also in the looser sense [of 'perhaps']
>
> zusammengeschoben aus
> vil
> und mhd.
> lîhte.
> letzteres allein hat im
> mhd. und noch dem älteren nhd. die bedeutung des nhd. adv.
> vielleicht,
> s. oben bd.
> 6,
> sp.
> 637 (leicht
> 17)
> ; mhd.
> vil lîhte
> wird nicht nur im sinne von
> '
> sehr leicht, ganz ohne schwierigkeit
> ',
> sondern schon in
> freierer bedeutung angewandt

*Kann sein* is indeed sometimes used in the sense of *vielleicht*, but more colloquial.

Comment: Indeed. Of course, the interpretation involves a certain ellipsis: "very easily (possible)", as @JoopEggen puts it, or "very easily (true)" or "very easily (could be the case)".

Answer (score 1):

The English **perhaps**: can happen, and the Dutch **misschien** (geschieden): might happen have similar roots.

The German **vielleicht** seems to deviate on first sight, but there is the Dutch **wel-licht** with the same meaning: "yes easily (possible)" - *wel* = indeed, yes, yeah (compare the English *well*). Both **vielleicht** and **wellicht** stem from the same spoken form evidently.